# azure search service and opening hours

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-search

Consider same situation, that Microsoft uses in their azure search examples - hotel search system, but azure search should provide filter for opened hotels.

Any ideas how to store information about opening hours (source model contains two intervals for each day - before/after lunch) to be useful for filters?

The easiest solution I've found (definitely not the prettiest one) was to create fields for each day, both intervals and both start and stop timestamps (only Time typed). Then use appropriate day values and current time in filter params. Whole solution needs 7 x 2 x 2 fields to be created.

Anyone with better solution, maybe using default features of Azure Search Engine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That approach would work. Here's an alternative approach that uses one field instead of 28: 
Let's say all of your open / close times are on 1-hour boundaries (of course, the same approach will work for 30-min or 15-min boundaries). 
For each hotel, generate terms for all intervals describing whether the hotel is open or closed at that time: "Mon12AMClosed", "Mon1AMClosed", ..., "Mon6AMOpened", ..., "Tue12AMClosed",..... Index all these terms into a string collection field. At query time, map the current time into the appropriate interval (such as "Wed12PMOpen" to find out which hotels are open on Wed in 12PM - 1PM interval), and use a filter expression similar to:

$filter = intervals/any(t: t eq "Wed12PMOpen")

HTH,
Eugene

Comment: Not a bad idea, not at all :-) Thank you.